# Creating auth token for non user object django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, token

I am looking to generate a django authtoken for a non user object. previously I had easily generated auth tokens for user objects like this

```
email = request.data.get('email')
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

but if I am trying this for non user object it is not getting generated.

```
device_id = request.data.get('device_id')
tablet = Table.objects.get(device_id=device_id)
Token.objects.create(user=tablet)
```

Here Table is simple model holding various device_ids.

I just want to generate an auth token for each tablet like we do for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **linking** devices to **users**, and need a "per device" token where a user has >1 device (e.g. desktop, tablet, phone, etc) that are logged in separately and where the tokens can be revoked, then look at the `Knox` App:

[Django Knox (https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox)](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox)

---

Otherwise, authentication tokens are normally used to log in a user.  If you don't have a user then they aren't much use as far as the standard infrastructure is concerned.

If you want something custom, then you'll have to write your own solution, which might include:

- A custom middleware if:

  - you want/need to set `request.device=`, like request.user
  - you want a custom user object (below)
- Decide if you want a "fake" user like `DeviceUser`

  - Implement the User interface (see `AnonymousUser`'s example)
  - Has is_authenticated=True
  - Has permissions (?)
  - Has is_device_user=True so you can distinguish
- Be really careful not to rely on `request.user` to have a user_id
- Possibly a new Permission class (e.g. a new `IsAuthenticated`)

The main problem I see is with things that expect a non-anonymous User object (in `request`) to be a *real* user with a pk. If you are careful then this might not be too big an issue, but you'll need to start implementing to be sure how it affects you.